# Using Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

I have two shapefiles, one polygons the other points.

I'm using Data Driven Page Setup, to produce a series of layout.

In the Index Layer I chose the shapefile of the polygons that have the OBJECTID that I use as reference for each Polygon.

How can I add the shapefile of the points so that I can get the X, Y, N_Order information that is in the Attributes table to get this information in the Dynamic Layout?

[image]

[image: Shp Point]

Comment: The attribute table shown above is a Point shapefile and you want attributes from this to be shown in data driven pages? Join the Point shapefile to the polygon shapefile. Or if the Points are centroids you can calculate these for the polygon shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Page Definition Queries](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/using-page-definition-queries.htm).

Go to the Properties of the point feature class and click on the Definition Query tab.  From there you will see a Page Definition button which will allow you to define what you want to show.  In your case where the OBJECTID field in your point feature class **matches** the OBJECTID from your polygon feature class.

Comment: It looks like you need to match ObjectID of the polygon table to the first field of the points file ending '_FID'. However, if you don't need to limit the displays to only the matches, a match and definition query are not needed; the spatial relationship between the polygon and points will be obvious in the maps.